# mysql - cannot create view that contains union

Tags: mysql, view, union

I have a mysql query that uses union to join multiple queries into one result set. the query works perfectly.

When I want to use the same query to create a view I then get an error message:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'union select hulaminloadnumber2,deliveryid,drop1customer from localjhb where hul' at line 2
```

my query that works perfectly is:

```
select hulaminloadnumber1,deliveryid,drop1customer from localjhb where hulaminloadnumber1>0
union
select hulaminloadnumber2,deliveryid,drop1customer from localjhb where hulaminloadnumber2>0
union
select hulaminloadnumber3,deliveryid,drop1customer from localjhb where hulaminloadnumber3>0
union
select hulaminloadnumber4,deliveryid,drop1customer from localjhb where hulaminloadnumber4>0
union
select hulaminloadnumber5,deliveryid,drop1customer from localjhb where hulaminloadnumber5>0
```

[image: query results]

my query to create the view is:

```
create view View_LoadvsCustomer as (
select hulaminloadnumber1,deliveryid,drop1customer from localjhb where hulaminloadnumber1>0
union
select hulaminloadnumber2,deliveryid,drop1customer from localjhb where hulaminloadnumber2>0
union
select hulaminloadnumber3,deliveryid,drop1customer from localjhb where hulaminloadnumber3>0
union
select hulaminloadnumber4,deliveryid,drop1customer from localjhb where hulaminloadnumber4>0
union
select hulaminloadnumber5,deliveryid,drop1customer from localjhb where hulaminloadnumber5>0)
```

this produces the below error in PHPMyadmin:
[image: error message]

The queries are all from a badly designed table so there should be no formatting or collation issues. Can a view be created against a union query?

Any advice is appreciated.

Have a GREAT weekend,
Ryan

Comment: All SELECT queries have the same condition - 'hulaminloadnumber1>0'. Is it correct?

Comment: Hi @Devart, you are right, sorry copies bad code. will correct question. The same error occurs however with the correct code. Thank

Comment: About the error - have a look at the Ashwin's A answer. It will fix it.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Remove the parenthesis from view definition. You have hit this server [bug](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=21614).

Comment: Thank you!  Exactly the problem & solution.  To help anybody searching in the future, this was the error I was getting:  `ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UNION DISTINCT SELECT...`